# Nested routing in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing

I've got, for example, 2 routes:

1. `/site/test`
2. `/site/test/foo`

I need to write rules for `UrlManager` so it'll pass first rule to `TestController` and second to `FooController`.

Can i actually do that?

Answer (score 2):

You are actually nesting 3 controllers, which i do not think is a really good idea, but you can do it like the following:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        'site/test/foo/<action\w+>' => 'foo/<action>',
        'site/test/<action\w+>' => 'test/<action>',
        'site/<action\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
        ...
    ],
],
```

Comment: Why is that not a good idea? What if i have /messages and /messages/comments for example? It's too much for 1 class.

Comment: it's more like i don't like having both test and foo inside site, also i usually don't use the site controller except for login, logout, error and index page, everything else i usually set on separate controllers or inside modules.